# Is there any obligation to invariably use commonplace collocations in English?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

For example, these four words are synonymous: *become, get, go, turn*. But
you would probably say *go crazy* and *become famous*, not *become crazy*
and *turn famous*.

However, is saying *become crazy* or *turn famous* instead considered
“incorrect”? Why or why not? How can you know for sure, especially if you are not a native
speaker?

Comment: My intuition as a native speaker says that *become crazy* is perfectly fine, although less idiomatic; but *go famous* is not anything anybody would ever say.. And [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=become+crazy%2Cwent+famous&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) confirms this.

Comment: 'Powerful tea' and a 'strong computer' may not be unacceptable, but the first connotes tea that will keep you awake and the second defaults to a computer that will take the odd knock. Synonyms are not interchangeable across the board, and it's best to take care when avoiding strong collocations. Some pairings, like Peter's second example, sound unnatural and might be considered unacceptable by some in line with Orwell's sixth law. And some pairings have a default sense not intended, obviously unacceptable if context doesn't clarify..

Comment: @PeterShor I deliberately chose examples that make sense if you only look at the definitions in the dictionary but in practice are not used. However, my question has been slightly modified.

Comment: [go crazy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20crazy) has its own entry on Merriam-Webster. I'm not sure if this is a request for resources (which is unfortunately off-topic) or about specific phrases (in which case you shouldn't ask 2 questions at once). You can get a sense of what's usual from the usage examples in dictionaries, by searching online, by looking at corpuses and Google NGrams, etc. This isn't an issue that's specific to English - all languages have certain words used in certain circumstances by habit or convention, and different connotations for different terms.

Comment: @StuartF 'I'm not sure if this is a request for resources (which is unfortunately off-topic) or about specific phrases (in which case you shouldn't ask 2 questions at once).' Neither. Read the title

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based upon a fatally flawed misunderstanding of "synonym."

Comment: @user81561 What? How come?

Comment: Your four words _can_ be synonymous in certain contexts; that doesn't mean that all of them can replace any other in all contexts.

Comment: @KateBunting They are synonymous in a certain meaning

Answer (score 3):

Words are like cut diamonds, and a synonym may line up only with one of the facets.

We wouldn't say "turn famous" because "turn" has a volitional aspect when a person is the subject of that verb:

> A mild-mannered pastor of a rural church, he turned bank robber.

So you cannot "turn famous", because no amount of willpower can make a person famous--the complement will be some kind of role, very broadly construed, or  an occupation that one can decide to become.

Here are some examples of what I mean by  "role ... very broadly construed":

> Johnny Two-Fingers turned rat and told the feds all about your little operation.
>
> Don't turn chicken. Are you going to ask her out or not?
>
> Only the most talented athletes are able to turn pro.

Morever, the verb "turn" has a different form of complement than the complement of "become".

> A mild-mannered pastor of a rural church, he turned *bank robber*.
>
> A mild-mannered pastor of a rural church, he became *a* bank robber.

So, if you are not a native speaker, you must learn the nuances either by paying careful attention to the contexts where the word is used or by using a good dictionary that offers example sentences that illustrate the contexts -- ideally multiple dictionaries.

It should go without saying that this is the same when learning any second language. It's not a challenge particular to learning English.

Comment: I doubt that this answer agrees with what the dictionaries state. According to the Oxford Learner's Dictionary: turn - linking verb to change into a particular state or condition; to make something do this. + adj. The leaves were turning brown. become - linking verb to start to be something + adj. It soon became apparent that no one was going to come.

Comment: Learner's dictionaries only get you so far.  Definitions are clumsy and often incomplete.   You reveal in your comment something that is perhaps part of your problem. You have overlooked an important phrase in my answer, "when a person is the subject of that verb:".   You also have to pay attention to transitive vs intransitive distinctions in the definitions offered.

Comment: Dictionaries may be wrong but there is no better source for learning the meaning of words. Dictionaries are professionally worked on by a team of specialists so will always be a better source than the opinion of a single person.

Comment: I don't need to be schooled on what dictionaries are.  They are not the best source for learning the meaning of words. They're simply the most convenient when you don't have time to read primary sources or opportunity to immerse yourself in the language in a land where it is the native language.

Comment: @Kyamond Dictionaries do not capture all of the nuance of English usage. If they did, there would be no need for this site. Leaves can turn brown. People can turn red. People don’t turn famous, they get or become famous.

Comment: @TimR English varies greatly regionally so immersion in one land is a singular experience. Also, what do you mean by 'primary sources'? Do you know how dictionaries are created? By looking into source texts such as books.

Comment: @ColleenV I don't have to deny that. It is about the quality of the sources, who to believe. Not about whether the source is infallible.

Comment: @ColleenV Maybe I'll put this in a different way. Do you have any sources to support this answer?

Comment: @Kyamond Yes, I do know how dictionaries are created; my academic background would qualify me to work for one of them if I wished to do so. If you're going to use a dictionary, use several of them.

Comment: @Kyamond You should not be arguing. 1. There are very, very few true synonyms in English. The guidance is "If a word or phrase is different then it will have a different meaning or nuance." 2. You have been told that collocations are determined by context. 3. A dictionary is a **very** poor resource for learning a language. 4. As it happens "become crazy" is correct, but "turn famous" is not.